# How to prevent duplicate request in chrome with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-fetch

As far as I know, the reason why duplication request is occurring in chrome is to get /favicon.ico in the first request and URI in the second request. But as you can see in my simple test code, exactly the same URL is being accessed for both requests, not for getting /favicon.ico from the first request. This brings unexpected result in my project.

**express Code**

```
app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(`URL : ${req.originalUrl}`);
    if(req.url=='/test'){
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    }else{
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
})
```

**result**

```
URL : /test
GET /test 200 - - 1.761 ms
URL : /test
GET /test 200 - - 0.612 ms
```

Comment: Check the network tab in chrome dev tools. What do you see?

Comment: First, request localhost:5000/test,then when I refresh, localhost:5000/favicon.ico is requested too.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of preventing it, By blocking the request from the network tab in dev tools.
[image]